# "Object controller", Entity mode: fetching is slow on Mavericks

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

It takes 5 seconds to load 8425 items on the last iMac.

[image]

I don't know what else add to provide you more info. I'm loading the items for the drop down list of a NSComboBox.

I've tested on Snow Leopard and Mountain Lion and it works fine. Tried on several machines, it works fine on all osx except for Mavericks. Same build and database files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that NSComboBox loads all items one by one and CoreData has to make a roundtrip to the disk each time. You should inspect this situation with Instruments to know for sure what's going on.

Try prefetching all items before showing them. You can use `-[NSFetchRequest returnsObjectsAsFaults:]` property set to `NO` during such fetch.

Here's a snippet from my project that does prefetching:

```
if ( ! didPrefetch)
{
    didPrefetch = YES;

    // Your fetch request that will load all items
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = ... ;

    // If you need to prefetch some relationships
    fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[...]; 

    // This forces objects to fault info row cache
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO; 

    [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}
```

Comment: On Instruments I can see that there is a high fetch duration for a specific entity. What more useful info could I get from it ? I'm using "CoreData Fetches" instrument. You suggest to set the properties programmatically? Then I can't rely on interface builder binding only?

Comment: By the way I've also tried to set the property "Use lazy fetching", without success.

Comment: I guess you don't have to get rid of bindings, but you need to do prefetching **before** NSComboBox tries to load data through bindings.

Comment: I've just found out, that the fetching is slow on Mavericks. I've run the app on Snow Leopard and Mountain Lion and it works good.

Comment: By the way, the items are surely fetched before NSComboBox is opened. They actually slow down the entire screen after its opening.